# RegEx: Grabbing all text between quotation marks (including nested), except if in a comment line (starting with //)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to put together an expression that will grab text between quotation marks (single or double), including text in nested quotes, but will ignore text in comments, so except if the line starts with //.

Code example:

```
// this is a "comment" and should be ignored
//this is also a 'comment' and should be ignored

printf("This is text meant to be "captured", and can include any type of character");
printf("This is the same as above, only with 'different' nested quotes");
```

This can be quite useful to extract translatable content from a file.

So far, I have managed to use `^((?!\/\/).)*` to exclude comment lines from being imported, and `["'](.+)["']` to extract text between quotes, but I haven't been able to combine it on a single expression.
Running them in a sequence also doesn't work, I think because of the greedy quantifier in the first expression.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are `//` the only style of comments in your program (i.e. no `/* */`s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is written nothing about type of input files and so I assume C source code files.

I suggest following regular expression tested with text editor UltraEdit which uses the
[Boost C++ Perl regular expression library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html).

```
^(?:(?!//|"|').)*(["'])(?!\1)\K(?:\\\1|.)+?(?=\1)
```

It matches **first** single or double quoted string on a line. Other strings on same line are ignored by this regular expression search string in Perl syntax which is not optimal.

It ignores single or double quoted strings in line comments starting with `//` independent on line comment being at start of a line without or with leading spaces/tabs or somewhere else on a line after code.

It ignores also empty strings like `""` or `''`. If a line contains first `""` or `''` and second one more single or double quoted non-empty string, the non-empty string is ignored, too. This is not optimal.

The string delimiting character is not matched on both sides of the matched string.

The string delimiting character must be escaped with a backslash character to be interpreted by this search expression as literal character inside the string. The first `printf` in example in question would definitely result in a syntax error on compilation by a C compiler.

Strings in block comments are not ignored by this expression as also strings in code ignored by compiler because of a preprocessor macro.

Example:

```
// This is a "comment" and should be ignored.
//This is also a 'comment' which should be ignored.
printf("This is text meant to be \"captured\", and can include any type of character.\n");  // But " must be escaped with a backslash.
printf("This is the same as above, only with 'different' nested quotes.\n");
putchar('I');
putchar('\'');
printf(""); printf("m thinking.");  // First printf is not very useful.
printf("\"OK!\"");
printf("Hello"); printf(" world!\n");
printf("%d file%s found.\n",iFileCount,((iFileCount != 1) ? "s" : "");
printf("Result is: %s\n",sText);  // sText is "success" or "failure".
return iReturnCode; // 0 ... "success", 1 ... "error"
```

The search expression matches for this example:

```
This is text meant to be \"captured\", and can include any type of character.\n
This is the same as above, only with 'different' nested quotes.\n
I
\'
\"OK!\"
Hello
%d file%s found.\n
Result is: %s\n
```

So it does not find all non-empty strings output on running C code example.

Explanation for search string:

- `^` ... start search at beginning of a line.
  This is the main reason why it is not possible to match with this expression second, third, ... string on a line not being in a line comment.
- `(?:(?!//|"|').)*` ... search with a non-marking group for zero or more characters not being a newline character on which next there is neither `//` nor `"` nor `'` verified with a negative look-ahead containing an OR expression.
  This expression is responsible for ignoring everything after `//` once found in a line because of
- `(["'])` ... `"` or `'` must be found next and found character is marked for back-referencing.
- `(?!\1)` ... but match is only positive if the next character is not the same character to ignore empty strings.
- `\K` ... resets the start location of `$0` to the current text position: in other words everything to the left of `\K` is "kept back" and does not form part of the regular expression match. So everything matched from beginning of line up to `"` or `'` at beginning of non-empty string is not matched (selected) anymore.
- `(?:\\\1|.)+?` ... non-marking group to find either a backslash and the character at beginning of the string or any character not being a newline character non-greedy one or more times.
  This expression matches the string of interest.
- `(?=\1)` ... matching any character not being a newline character should stop on next character (positive look-ahead) being the same quote character not escaped with a backslash as at beginning of the string without matching this quote character.

For matching **first** non-empty string outside a line comment with the delimiting character on both sides:

```
^(?:(?!//|"|').)*\K(["'])(?!\1)(?:\\\1|.)+?\1
```

**How to get really all non-empty strings outside of comments?**

1. Copy content of entire C source code file into a new file.
2. Remove in new file all not nested block comments and all line comments with the search expression:
   `^[\t ]*//.*[\r\n]+|[\t ]*/\*[\s\S]+?\*/[\r\n]*|[\t ]*//.*$`
   The replace string is an empty string.
   Note: `//` inside a string is interpreted by third part of OR expression also as beginning of a line comment although this it not correct.
3. Use as search string `(["'])(?!\1)(?:\\\1|.)+?\1` to find really all non-empty strings with matching also the string delimiting character on both sides of every string.

Best would parsing a C source code file with a program written in C for non-empty strings because of such a program could much better find out what is a line comment, what is a block comment even on source code file containing nested block comments and what are non-empty strings. Well, it would be also possible to let the C compiler just preprocess the C source code files of a project with generating the output files after preprocessing with all line and block comments already removed and search in those preprocessed files for non-empty strings.

Comment: Brilliant! The code is in a Java-based proprietary language, not C, but I've tested and this would work perfectly! Thanks!